# RESTful API - WooCommerce REST API requests failing with curl

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce, restful-authentication

I have recently updated to the latest version of WooCommerce 2.1 which includes a [new RESTful API](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/).
I don't have much experience with cURL or RESTful APIs but I thought I give it a play.

My site is sergedenimes.com and I have SSL set up on the server.

If I run `curl https://sergedenimes.com/wc-api/v1` I get a nice long bit of json output like so:

```
{
   "store":{
      "name":"Serge DeNimes",
      "description":"Original, Urban T-Shirts Of The Highest Quality by Oliver Proudlock",
      "URL":"http:\/\/sergedenimes.com",
      "wc_version":"2.1.2",
      "routes":{
         "\/":{
            "supports":[
               "HEAD",
               "GET"
            ],
            "meta":{
               "self":"http:\/\/sergedenimes.com\/wc-api\/v1\/"
            }
         },
         "\/customers":{ etc.....
```

This suggests the api itself is working. However when I pass a request that uses authentication:

```
curl https://sergedenimes.com/wc-api/v1/orders -u my_key:my_secret
```

I get this in response:

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error",
         "message":"Consumer Key is missing"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is my syntax correct? I have set up my key and secret under the WP admin and passed in the values but it seems to think I'm not passing it with my request.

Any ideas?

Comment: I stuck at the same place of you. Can you share the full url?

Comment: The full URL is in my question. @Gerhard's answer has solved it. If you still have trouble, passing the auth credentials as GET parameters can be a workaround if your server struggles with the auth being sent in the header (basic auth only). E.g. `https://example.com/wc-api/v1/orders?consumer_key=ck_7xxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_7xxxxxx`

Comment: Also, [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) is a handy tool for testing APIs without fiddling with curl etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have secure checkout option enabled under WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout. It will only use basic auth if you have that option enabled.

Comment: I also wrote this handy client library to make interacting with the API easier http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2014/02/10/woocommerce-rest-api-client-library/

Comment: Yes I stumbled across that whilst on my googling hunt. I'll be sure to refer to it should I ever need to make practical use of the API. I guess it is most useful to order fulfillers and I will refer our current provider to the relevant tools. (They use CSV export at the moment)

Comment: Hi Gerhard. I have the same issue. I change the checkout too, But still same error. can you please help me? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699089/woocommerce-rest-api-request-returns-error/25707283#25707283]