# WooCommerce REST API request returns error

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

I'm developing a shopping cart Site and an App. I want to get product details from DB for my App, So I have recently used JSON REST API (WP API), And also latest version of 
WooCommerce 2.1.

When I run my url `http://ishop/wc-api/v1/`  I get a long json output,
So I can make sure the API is working fine.

However when I pass a request like this:

```
http://ishop/wc-api/v1/products?consumer_key=ck_asd78465&consumer_secret=cs_d75412
```

Error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}
```

Anything wrong in my syntax? Please help guys.

Comment: You don't want to send your credentials like that, anyone can see that.

Comment: Hi PinkAngel, have you ever found a solution for this? I am having the same issue. I am building an app for a Woocommerce site and I need to pull some products and show them in the app. I have added the library on the server in the root of the website but I get the woocommerce_api_authentication_error. Where have you added the library? I am completely stuck right now and really hope you'll be able to help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ether HTTPS or a OAuth signature as described here: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce/rest-api/#authentication

There is a client library that can help you with the signature if you want to use HTTP. You can find the library here: https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

Comment: Appreciate Pelmered. I'm a beginner to these stuffs. Can you please  tell me where should I place the library `WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library`. Inside my theme or plugin folder?

Comment: In the same place as you use the library. If you use it in your theme code, put the library in your theme.

Comment: Can I use this Library for my mobile app?

Comment: Well, it's written in PHP and I don't think you can run PHP-code in a native app. You would probably need some middleware on a server if you want to use this Library. You would then send requests to the middleware from your app and then let the middleware use the WooCommerce API.

However, if you don't need to process the data before sending it to the app, it's probably better to let the app connect to the API directly.

Comment: @Pelmered the Provided `WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library` Works Perfect But the issue is it is not adding Attributes to the store Can you help me on that Hear is MY QUESTION:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335073/api-v2-of-woocommerce-add-attributes-to-product?noredirect=1#comment52545750_32335073

Comment: Hi @Pelmered, I am also confused for where to add the library. I have a woocommerce website and creating a separated hybrid app for it. I need to pull the products from the website and show them into the app. I am also using the REST API Client Library and I have added it on the server in the root of the website but I get the `woocommerce_api_authentication_error`. What do you mean to place it "in the same place as you use the library"? I need to use the library on the app in a js file. I have also tried placing the library in the root of the app but that also doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: This client is written in PHP.  That means that it will only run on a server. If you want to run it inside a hybrid app you need a client written in Javascript.