# API v2 of WooCommerce add attributes to Product

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to add a Product via API v2 of WooCommerce Wc_API_Client to wp-store the Below code in the below code i have no idea where am i going wrong my below attributes section is not adding attributes to the products thow i have created a attribute by name Color and has options Red And white everything seem to be working good the product is to added but the attribute is the one was not included

```
   print_r( $client->products->create( array( 'title' => 'Franky9','sku' => 'Franky9', 'type' => 'simple', 'regular_price' => '1000', 'short_description'=>'short description', 'attributes' => Array ('name'=>'pa_color','options'=>'Red' ) )  ) ) ;
```

Comment: I don't believe v2 version of api supports adding product attributes, 2.4 of woocommerce will contain this option v3 -- check out https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php#L74-L85

Comment: @Fresher to be frank, i really do not know what is the version of the api i am using. i have made a code of myself with few references. To be clear, i am getting a output in reverse print ` [attributes] => Array ( ) [downloads] => Array ( )` - which means the attributes are seen and good to work provided my code is perfect to ensure it works..can you help ?

Comment: @Fresher can you give me a url where i can download v3 from ?

Comment: are you using client rest api from kloon?

Comment: Yes not shore downloaded from https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

Comment: i hope you are using woocommerce 2.4.x right?

Comment: then open lib folder inside  open woocommerce-api in there class-wc-api-client.php file open that one in line 161 you can see something like `$path .= '/wc-api/v2/'; ` then change it to `$path .= '/wc-api/v3/'; `that's all now you can able to save attributes

Comment: It gives the error after changing :Error: Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match [woocommerce_api_authentication_error] 401 stdClass Object

Comment: `rror: Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match [woocommerce_api_authentication_error] 401 stdClass Object ( [headers] => Array ( [0] => Accept: application/json [1] => Content-Type: application/json [2] => User-Agent: WooCommerce API Client-PHP/2.0.1 ) [method] => POST [url] => `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88497/discussion-between-shaik-asif-and-fresher).

Comment: @Fresher waiting for your reply on chat

Comment: https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/issues might be the best place to report the issue as you get it now

Answer (score 0):

I am using [kloon-WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library). If you want to use for wc-api v3. I read through the authentication process in class-wc-api-authentication.php and found the difference was I needed to append an unencoded & to the consumer secret before using it to sign my parameter string.

```
$secret = $consumer_secret . '&';
```

Also change the path to v3:

```
$path .= '/wc-api/v3/';
```