# Curl API v3 not working for Product Creating - Authentication Error

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to Upload the Product to Woo commerce Store but on upload it gives me the below Error code am not sure where am going Wrong.
and I am note Sure on one Case to Should i have to include any Lib to make work if help me on that
 FYI: this is a V3 API code of woocommerce
Error Code

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}
```

My Code

```
    $aData = array(
    'product' => array(
    'title' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple'

    )
    );
    $sData = json_encode($aData);
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/demo/ir/wc-api/v3/products');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sData);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');                           
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($sData))                                                                       
    ); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WooCommerce REST API request returns error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699089/woocommerce-rest-api-request-returns-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [kloon-WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library).
I had a similar problem after upgrading to v3. I read through the authentication process in class-wc-api-authentication.php and found the difference was I needed to append an unencoded & to the consumer secret before using it to sign my parameter string.

```
$secret = $consumer_secret . '&';
```